# Wix Bootstrapper Payload destination

Tags: wix, wix3.7, burn

I have a burn installer that I need to install .NET 4.5 as a prereq (not for the installer UI, but for the product I am installing).  However, one requirement is I cannot download it during the install.  I added the payload and the file gets included, but it will not come out at a relative path of redist\dotnet45full_x86_x64.exe.  I have not been able to find any resources that describe how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

[ExePackage/@Name](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html)

> The destination path and file name for this chain payload. Use this attribute to rename the chain entry point or **extract it into a subfolder**. The default value is the file name from the SourceFile attribute, if provided. At a minimum, the Name or SourceFile attribute must be specified.

So use

```
<ExePackage Name="redist\dotnet45full_x86_x64.exe" ... />
```